# PHP aggregate - sum of two fields

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a query as below:

```
$pipeline  = array( 
  array(
    '$match' => $query,
  ),
  array(
   '$group' => array( 
      '_id' => '$_id', 
      's_count' => array('$sum' => array('$add' => array('value1' , 'value2' ))),
    ) 
  ),
  array(
    '$sort' => array(
      'id' => -1
    )
  )
);

$result = $this->db->aggregate( 'table',$pipeline );
```

In the above query, value 1 and value 2 are declared as strings in my table, but its values are numbers.

Is there any way to parse my fields as integer in group sum stage, as it is throwing error "Only numeric values allowed for $sum aggregation"

**EDITED**

My requirement is like: there are two fields `value1` and `value2` in my table.

I need to get all the records with sum of those two fields in an order ie max to min.

Because in my view page, I have to paginate and display. So at the time of pagination it is returning results in an order max to min within the 10 records( I have given sort condition after query processing).

I need to display 10 records first out of which it should be sorted in such a way that first record's sum of those two fields should be maximum in my table.. in that manner I have to display.

Comment: `intval ` will get the integer value of a variable.. After that should be easy. What have you tried ?

Comment: i tried as below.                                                                               's_count' => array('$sum' => array('$add' => array((int)'value1' , (int)'value2' )))   but it is wrong..Where should i give intval ? as type cast u mean?

Comment: No, there's no way (as of 2.6) to have the aggregation pipeline interpret a string value as an integer value - you will need to change your documents.

Comment: IS there any other way to fullfill the same requirement where i can compute the sum of two table values and get their mongoids based on the sorted order?

Comment: Is there any other way to compute the sum of two table values ( whose datatype is  string) and need to sort the table by the output sum value ?